# Display full word instead of notation - compactDisplay: "long"

Tags: javascript

```
new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "INR",
      notation: "compact",
      compactDisplay: "long"
    }).format(36000000);
```

returns `₹3.6Cr`

Is there a way to display Cr as crores ?

`compactDisplay: "long"` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont found any relevant option under `unit`. So if it works then you can use string replace

```js
const z = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "INR",
  notation: "compact",
  compactDisplay: "long",
  unitDisplay: "long",
}).format(35000000).replace('Cr', 'Crores');

console.log(z)
```

Comment: Also TypeScript complains - `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'compactDisplay' does not exist in type 'NumberFormatOptions'.`